# MySQL syntax help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I am completely stuck on this and would appreciate help from someone who is more fluent in sql than me!

Situation: I have Images which can belong to up to 3 Categories. I have to look them up using the category name (e.g. 'School').  I have an Image table, a Category table, and a CategoryImage table as a join table

The essential fields are

```
Category
    Id
    categoryname
Image
    Id
    imagename
    description
CategoryImage
    categoryId
    imageId
```

If Image '001' belongs to the categories called 'School' and 'Home' it will have 2 entries in CategoryImage.

I need the sql to find all images which are in BOTH the 'School' AND the 'Home' category.  I can see that this sql is probably trying to return a single image where the category is 'School AND 'Home' which is clearly impossible.  [ Changing the AND to an OR finds images which be log to the 'School' category plus also images which belong to the 'Home' category, which is not what I need.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT t0.description, 
   t0.imagename
FROM 
   Image t0, Category T2, CategoryImage T1 
WHERE 
  (T2.name = "School" 
  AND T2.name = "Home")  
  AND T1.categoryId = T2.id 
  AND t0.id = T1.imageId
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Suggestion #0, stop using implict joins. Use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: And how `T2.name = "School" AND T2.name = "Home"` can be possible?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "IN('x','y') ... GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: Either change the AND to OR in your `T2.Name =` test, or change it to `WHERE T2.Name IN ('School', 'Home')`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).

Comment: Find images of one category and theother one separately and UNION results.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
select distinct t0.description 
     , t0.imagename 
from categoryimage T1 
join image t0 on t0.id = T1.imageid 
join category T2 on T1.categoryid = T2.id 
where  T2.name in ( 'School', 'Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get you all images which are in both the school and home categories

```
SELECT 
   i.description, 
   i.imagename
FROM 
   Image i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Category c 
              INNER JOIN CategoryImage ci ON ci.categoryid=c.id 
              WHERE ci.imageid=i.id AND c.name="School")
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Category c 
              INNER JOIN CategoryImage ci ON ci.categoryid=c.id 
              WHERE ci.imageid=i.id AND c.name="Home")
```

Comment: IMHO, two correlated subqueries look worse then UNION of two HASH JOINS

Comment: @NaeelMaqsudov - I am pretty sure your SQL will include all images which exist in either school or home categories. The OP is looking for ones which exist in both.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t0.description, t0.imagename
FROM 
  Image t0 
  INNER JOIN CategoryImage T1 ON (t0.id = T1.imageId)
  INNER JOIN Category T2 ON (T1.categoryId = T2.id)
WHERE 
  T2.name = "School"
UNION
SELECT 
  t0.description, t0.imagename
FROM 
  Image t0 
  INNER JOIN CategoryImage T1 ON (t0.id = T1.imageId)
  INNER JOIN Category T2 ON (T1.categoryId = T2.id)
WHERE 
  T2.name = "Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(i.description), i.imagename 
FROM CategoryImage ci 
LEFT JOIN Category c
ON ci.categoryId = c.Id
LEFT JOIN Image i 
ON ci.imageId = i.Id
WHERE c.categoryname IN ( 'School', 'Home' )
```